# Using $(this) selector in jquery with another nested selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, attr

What is the best way to specify a nested selector when using `$(this)`?

In this example:

```
$('.example').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

`url` would return `undefined`, because it would expects an `'a'` selector first.
So ideally i would want to say:

```
var url = $(this, 'a').attr('href');
```

but that does not work, the following works as intended but doesn't look very tidy:

```
$('.example').each(function() {
    var link = $(this).find('a');
    var url = $(link).attr('href');
});
```

so how can i use `$(this)` and `'a'` together correctly?

---

**note:** i know the following would work, but not for the purposes of my question.

```
 $('.example > a').each(function() {
     var url = $(this).attr('href');
 });
```

Comment: `$(this, 'a')` should be `$('a', this)`. The context of the search is unintuitively the second argument.

Comment: @cookiemonster this was all i wanted to know, although other answers provided work equally as well, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
$(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: As a side note, when tested against other methods, this turned out to be the quickest method (only marginally, but it was still the quickest).

Answer (score 0):

*(This should be a comment, but I needed more space for code).*

When you say

> it would expects an 'a' selector first

what exactly do you mean with "it"? There is nothing there that "expects" anything. Any element (theoretically) could have a `href` attribute.

Also, how does your HTML look like? If it's

```
<a class="example" href="#">...</a>
```

then only your first example works, the others don't. Your other examples all expect

```
<div class="example"><a href="#">...</a></div>
```

which in turn doesn't work with the first example.

What exactly is the problem? If `$(this).attr("href")` returns undefined, then you can easily check for that. Can you give a concrete use case?